# application on L.C.M and G,C,F

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Please I need help on the following problem:
The L.C.M and G.C.F of numbers x,18 and 60 are 360 and 6 respectively. What will be the value of x?
I know how to find in the case when given two numbers , but for this case I get difficult.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $18=2 \cdot 3^2$, $60=2^2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5$, $x=2^? \cdot 3^? \cdot 5^?$, $6=2 \cdot 3$, $360=2^3 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5$.

Answer (score 0):

I will express the 3 numbers as product of primes (fundamental theorem of arithmetic)

$18=2*3^2$

$60=2^2*3*5$

x=?

lcm is the product of the max powers of the primes so in this case its 360

$360=2^3*3^2*5$ from this I can deduce x can vary from 360 to $2^3=8$

hcf insteads choses the min powers of the primes

6=2*3 now 2 and 3 must be common to all so $x=2^3*3=24$